# ejabberd External Auth (PHP & MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, ejabberd

When I start the server, it loops with the following error message:

```
C(<0.1211.0>:extauth:146) : extauth script has exitted abruptly with reason 'normal'
```

I'm using a PHP script I found on ejabberd's site. https://www.ejabberd.im/files/efiles/check_mysql.php.txt

Permissions should be correct and that error is the only one I get. Is the script outdated? Any idea on what might help?

I can provide more log files if you can tell me which would be more helpful.

Comment: I think the script is indeed outdated. Why don't you use native ejabberd authentication against MySQL database ?

Comment: You need to also do the following. Tell which OS you are using and which ejabberd version. Show you config file, to make sure it is properly configured for your OS.

Comment: Other questions: Did you properly adapt the script to connect to your db ? What are the log file output of that script saying ?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it! I'm using Ubuntu and I believe the latest ejabberd version (2.1.11). I wanted to use a PHP external auth script because I'm using password_verify for authentication and I do not know how I could use that function with the native ejabberd authentication. I didn't bother trying to check the logs of the script (didn't even log) because I though the problem would be with the execution / script itself. The script is adapted but configured to return true, anyway.

Comment: Without logging, it is hard to tell if your script is even run and what is failing there. Do you have a final version of the script that you adapted somewhere ?

Comment: The log files aren't created, so I guess the script is either not running or permissions are missing. The script I adapted is exactly the same as the one I linked to above, just checkpass and checkuser modified to always return true and logging turned on.

Comment: Do you by chance know any other script example? I can't find a proper documentation on this and the script I linked to is the only PHP example I found.

Comment: I am not aware of an up to date script and I am not really into PHP, but I may have a look sometimes if I have a moment. No promise, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given script is outdated. I have slightly change it as follows. This is working for me. Give a try

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

error_reporting(0);


$auth = new JabberAuth();
$auth->dbhost = "localhost";
$auth->dbuser = "root";
$auth->dbpass = "123456";
$auth->dbbase = "ejabberd";
$auth->play(); // We simply start process !

class JabberAuth {
    var $dbhost; /* MySQL server */
    var $dbuser; /* MySQL user */
    var $dbpass; /* MySQL password */
    var $dbbase; /* MySQL database where users are stored */

    var $jabber_user;   /* This is the jabber user passed to the script. filled by $this->command() */
    var $jabber_pass;   /* This is the jabber user password passed to the script. filled by $this->command() */
    var $jabber_server; /* This is the jabber server passed to the script. filled by $this->command(). Useful for VirtualHosts */
    var $jid;           /* Simply the JID, if you need it, you have to fill. */
    var $data;          /* This is what SM component send to us. */

    var $dateformat = "M d H:i:s"; /* Check date() for string format. */
    var $command; /* This is the command sent ... */
    var $mysock;  /* MySQL connection ressource */
    var $stdin;   /* stdin file pointer */
    var $stdout;  /* stdout file pointer */

    function JabberAuth()
    {

        $this->openstd();
    }

    function stop()
    {

        closelog();
        $this->closestd(); // Simply close files
        exit(0); // and exit cleanly
    }

    function openstd()
    {
        $this->stdout = @fopen("php://stdout", "w"); // We open STDOUT so we can read
        $this->stdin  = @fopen("php://stdin", "r"); // and STDIN so we can talk !
    }

    function readstdin()
    {
        $l      = @fgets($this->stdin, 3); // We take the length of string
        $length = @unpack("n", $l); // ejabberd give us something to play with ...
        $len    = $length["1"]; // and we now know how long to read.
        if($len > 0) { // if not, we'll fill logfile ... and disk full is just funny once
            $data   = @fgets($this->stdin, $len+1);
            $this->data = $data; // We set what we got.

        }
    }

    function closestd()
    {
        @fclose($this->stdin); // We close everything ...
        @fclose($this->stdout);
    }

    function out($message)
    {
        @fwrite($this->stdout, $message); // We reply ...
        $dump = @unpack("nn", $message);
        $dump = $dump["n"];
    }

    function myalive()
    {
        if(!is_resource($this->mysock) || !@mysql_ping($this->mysock)) { // check if we have a MySQL connection and if it's valid.
            $this->mysql(); // We try to reconnect if MySQL gone away ...
            return @mysqli_ping($this->mysock); // we simply try again, to be sure ...
        } else {
            return true; // so good !
        }
    }

    function play()
    {
        do {
            $this->readstdin(); // get data
            $length = strlen($this->data); // compute data length
            $ret = $this->command(); // play with data !
            $this->out($ret); // send what we reply.
            $this->data = NULL; // more clean. ...
        } while (true);
    }

    function command()
    {


        $data = $this->splitcomm(); // This is an array, where each node is part of what SM sent to us :
        // 0 => the command,
        // and the others are arguments .. e.g. : user, server, password ...

        if($this->myalive()) { // Check we can play with MySQL

            switch($data[0]) {
                case "isuser": // this is the "isuser" command, used to check for user existance
                        $this->jabber_user = $data[1];
                        $return = $this->checkuser();
                    break;

                case "auth": // check login, password
                        $this->jabber_user = $data[1];
                        $this->jabber_pass = $data[3];
                        $return = $this->checkpass();

                    break;

                case "setpass":
                        $return = false; // We do not want jabber to be able to change password
                    break;

                default:
                        $this->stop(); // if it's not something known, we have to leave.
                        // never had a problem with this using ejabberd, but might lead to problem ?
                    break;
            }



            return @pack("nn", 2, $return);
        } else {

            return @pack("nn", 2, 0); // it's so bad.
        }
    }

    function checkpass()
    {
        /*
         * Put here your code to check password
         * $this->jabber_user
         * $this->jabber_pass
         * $this->jabber_server
         */
        if(1) { // You need to modify this
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function checkuser()
    {
        /*
         * Put here your code to check user
         * $this->jabber_user
         * $this->jabber_pass
         * $this->jabber_server
         */
        if(1) { // You need to modify this
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function splitcomm() // simply split command and arugments into an array.
    {
        return explode(":", $this->data);
    }

    function mysql() // "MySQL abstraction", this opens a permanent MySQL connection, and fill the ressource
    {

        $this->mysock = mysqli_connect($this->dbhost,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass,$this->dbbase);

    }
}

?>
```